# Alguna otra forma para codificar a Base 64 en Android?

Tags: java, android, base64

**java.util.Base64**

Quiero codificar la contraseña a base 64, pero solo encontré esa clase para condificar y decodificar, el problema es que solo es compatible a partir de la API 26 y como compatibilidad minima utilizo la API 21

Comment: Hola Jhony, bienvenido a [es.so] te recomiendo hacer el [tour] para ver el funcionamiento del sitio y además ganar tu primera [medalla.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed) Por otro lado te sugiero visitar [ask] para ver como realizar las preguntas y que sean mejor recibidas. Dando un ejemplo de código o el problema que te está dando.

Answer (score 3):

Respuesta encontrada en [StackOverflow:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47431337/base64-support-for-different-api-levels)

Utiliza **`android.util.Base64`** solucionará tu problema, está disponible desde la API 8

```
data= android.util.Base64.decode(str, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
```